# How to scope a PostgreSQL sub-query to a specific field without knowing the path / alias?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have several jsonb fields that have similar structures:

```sql
create table dog (id text, leftear jsonb, rightear jsonb);

insert into dog (id, leftear, rightear) values
  ('a', '{"itchy": false}', '{"itchy": false}'),
  ('b', '{"itchy": true}',  '{"itchy": false}'),
  ('c', '{"itchy": false}', '{"itchy": true}'),
  ('d', '{"itchy": true}',  '{"itchy": true}');
```

I have a query builder that spits out raw SQL like:

```js
itchy == true
```

It could also output the casting if that was helpful:

```js
itchy::boolean IS TRUE
```

The query builder knows nothing of which ear it's querying. I'd prefer to keep it that way. Is it possible to design my sql such that this query could be applied to either ear? Here are my attempts so far:

```js
-- subquery must know which ear
select id from dog where (leftear->'itchy')::boolean IS TRUE;

-- requires schema declaration and subquery must know alias
select id from dog, jsonb_to_record(dog.leftear) as le(itchy boolean) where le.itchy IS TRUE;

-- uses containment, so not powerful enough
select id from dog where leftear @> '{"itchy": true}'::jsonb;

-- better but requires alias and wow, that syntax...
select id from dog where jsonb_path_exists(leftear, '$.itchy ? (@ == true)');

-- maybe the best I can do? alias never changes and no casting is nice
select id from dog where leftear @? '$ ? (@.itchy == true)'::jsonpath;
```

Here's a [db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/6166). In the perfect world, I'm looking for something like this:

```sql
-- this is not valid syntax
select id from dog where leftear matches (itchy == true)
```

Comment: difficult to follow you : a/ your question = "Is it possible to design my sql such that this query could be applied to either ear?" whereas in all your attemps you only test the leftear column ? b/ why is the 3rd query using `@>` operator is not powerful enough ? c/ I don't se  why the query in the perfect world would be better than the previous ones ? Can you clarify the result you expect and the constraints you have ?

Comment: Thanks @Edouard - (a) yeah, i'd be querying both ears - just trying to keep the example simple, (b) I don't believe `@>` can do "or" clauses, greater-than, etc, (c) the "perfect" query has no casting, no alias, and a simple/readable/composable syntax

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
  FROM dog
 WHERE jsonb_path_exists(
         to_jsonb(dog) -- convert the whole record to jsonb
       , '$.*.itchy ? (@ == true)' -- looking one level down for any true 'itchy'
       )
;
```

or, more tersely

```
SELECT *
  FROM dog
 WHERE to_jsonb(dog) @? '$.*.itchy ? (@ == true)'
;
```

No aliases to be found, but includes whole record.